# OSGi dependencies management

Tags: osgi-bundle

I am using OSGi deploying bundles Apache Felix container. I have a maven project(~100bundles) and use maven-scr-plugin for generating manifest files and DS descriptors, I have a problem similar to the code described bellow. I need the ClassB not to activate until all the providers are not injected in ClassA(it would be great if there is a solution without touching ClassA, but its possible). The Provider2 is added to ClassA after the ClassB calls it's activate method that's why I get a "default" value in output. If I trigger print method later it works as expected.

If anybody has experienced with OSGi please advice. Thank you in advance.

```
public interface I1{
   String getMessage(String key);
}

public interface IProvider{
   String getMessage(String key);
}
bundle1:
@Component
public class ClassA implements I1{
    List<IProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.AT_LEAST_ONE, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    public synchronized void addProvider(IProvider provider) {
        providers.add(provider);
    }
    public String getMessage(String key){
        String message = null;
        for(IProvider provider: providers){
            message = provider.getMessage(key);
            if(message!=null){
                return message;
            }
        }
        return "default"
    }
}
```

bundle2:

```
@Component
public class Provider1 implements IProvider{

    public getMessage(String key){
       if(key.equals("key1")){
           return "value1";
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

bundle3:

```
@Component
public class Provider2 implements IProvider{    
    public getMessage(String key){
       if(key.equals("key2")){
           return "value2";
       }
       return null;
    }    
}
```

bundle4:

```
public interface I2{
    print();
}
@Component
public class ClassB implement I2{

    private I1 impl;

    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY, policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    public void setService(I1 aService) {
        impl = service;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(impl.getMessage("key1"));
        System.out.println(impl.getMessage("key2"));
    }

    @Activate
    public void activate(){
        print();    
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
value1
default
```